# return a list of all elements present in one column that is not present in the other

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula

I'm trying to create column where there are hundreds of items in a and b column, and I want to remove common items in b column and list them in different column in excel or google sheet.

| a | b | items present in b column only |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a1 | a1 | a5 |
| a2 | a2 | a6 |
| a3 | `a5` |  |
| a4 | `a6` |  |

Comment: excel or google sheets. Excel I would prefer.

Comment: For Excel: [How To Find Intersection Of Two Column Lists In Excel?](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/5242-excel-find-intersection-if-two-lists.html),   and   [What is Intersect Operator in Excel and How to Use it](https://trumpexcel.com/intersect-operator-in-excel/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Excel**:

[image]

Formula in `C2`:

```
=FILTER(B2:B5,COUNTIF(B2:B5,A2:A5)=0)
```

---

**Google-Sheets:**

Almost the same, but less explicit: `=FILTER(B2:B,COUNTIF(B2:B,A2:A)=0)`